# How to fix access denied even as owner when cleaning the cache?

Tags: linux, command-line, apt, dependencies

I am trying to clean the cache. I am running linux penguin 4.19.79 using a chromebook. I have run apt clean and apt-get clean to no avail. I get permission design. I have attached a screenshot of the error I get. I'm the root user.

[apt clean permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROqug.jpg)

I hope somone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Don't do screen shots like that.  copy the text and ask direct questions with what you did try. 
Are you sure your root I see a $ prompt on the screen shot, or su - before the command? Most all apt commands require elevated privileges.

Comment: 'penguin' is a container under ChromeOS for the termina VM as per https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/containers_and_vms.md#Overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running any command on the 'open' terminal (actually chroot'd inside of its own container) you have to put { sudo apt clean }because the privileges you have are given to you from... well, google I presume. It took me awhile to catch up on that, I have the same on my chromebook. Also, as Mark Stewart said try run su first and then try it. If you run into a snag there, be it for whatever reason you can use "sudo sudo /bin/bash" which will run you in another instance of bash, effectively making you root. Then run "passwd" to set a new one and exit to return to the normal user mode. Then when you run su the password you just set should work.

Comment: sudo sudo /bin/bash works like a charm.